# TransactionTemplate in scheduled job results in NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

I have simple schedulled job to run some worker to run something else in separate transaction using TransactionTemplate. It's a derivate from my project where it simply doesn't work.

The sandboxed project looks like this:

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>name.jikra.sandbox</groupId>
    <artifactId>transactions</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.18.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Application class**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@Configuration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean(name = "myExecutor")
    public ThreadPoolTaskExecutor myExecutor() {
        final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(3);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        executor.setThreadNamePrefix("myExecutor-");
        return executor;
    }
}
```

**Job**

```
@Component
public class SomeJob {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeJob.class);

    private final ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor;

    private final SomeWorker someWorker;

    private int counter;

    @Autowired
    public SomeJob(@Qualifier("myExecutor") ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor, SomeWorker someWorker) {
        this.executor = executor;
        this.someWorker = someWorker;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
    public void runJob() {
        counter++;
        logger.info("Job: " + counter);
        someWorker.executeJob(counter);
    }
}
```

**Worker**

```
@Component
public class SomeWorker {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SomeWorker.class);

    private final SomeService someService;

    @Autowired
    public SomeWorker(SomeService someService) {
        this.someService = someService;
    }

    @Async("myExecutor")
    public void executeJob(int counter) {
        int result = getResult();

        logger.info("Result = " + result + " in " + counter);
    }

    private int getResult() {
        return new TransactionTemplate().execute(new TransactionCallback<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer doInTransaction(TransactionStatus transactionStatus) {
                return someService.getResult();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Service**

```
@Service
public class SomeService {

    public int getResult() {
        return 999;
    }
}
```

Now, when I run my application, scheduler works fine but there is NullPointerException while calling TransactionTemplate.

```
2018-08-17 12:32:03.263 ERROR 7332 --- [pool-1-thread-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
        java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:130) ~[spring-tx-4.3.18.RELEASE.jar:4.3.18.RELEASE]
        at name.jikra.sandbox.transactions.SomeWorker.getResult(SomeWorker.java:34) ~[classes/:na]
        at name.jikra.sandbox.transactions.SomeWorker.executeJob(SomeWorker.java:28) ~[classes/:na]
        at name.jikra.sandbox.transactions.SomeJob.runJob(SomeJob.java:35) ~[classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor11.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:65) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_80]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_80]
```

I tried to remove `@Async` annotation and other stuff but nothing changes. Still the same error. Does anybody know, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you have spring-boot-starter and spring-tx as dependency? What part of Spring Boot do you want to use? JPA, Database?

Comment: spring-tx is there only because of TransactionTemplate dependency. It's not included in spring-boot-starter. I just wanted to test transaction in scheduled job.

Comment: I see and why don't you use Spring Boot 2?

Comment: But you have not configured any transaction manager. If you use a datasource there will be an autoconfigured transaction manager. but as long as you don't have any resource that needs a transaction manager there is none.

Comment: I don't use spring-boot 2 because my main project runs on java 7.

Comment: @SimonMartinelli You are right. I need to configure PlatformTransactionManager. My fault. Thanks.
If you convert your comment to an answer, I'll give you green.

Comment: Thanks. I add the comment as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not configured any transaction manager.

If you use a datasource there will be an autoconfigured transaction manager. But as long as you don't have any resource that needs a transaction manager there is none.